# Searching Only Blog Posts From a WordPress Site's Main Posts Page?

Tags: cms, search

On my CMS-style setup, I have the standard search box which searches everything.

However, on my blog page, I would like to also have another search box which searches just the blog... is this possible, and how would I go about it?

**EDIT**

I used this code within a text widget which goes on my blog page:

```
<form  id='searchform' method='get'>
<input style='margin-top:5px;' type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search (blog only)'>
<input type='hidden' name='post_type' value='post' />
</form>
```

This has the advantage that the results page is styled like the blog, and not the standard search page. (though I don't know how to indicate that the page is showing search results.. how to show this?)

Comment: Would it work for the blog search box to be limited to searching posts only?

Comment: Hi *@cannyboy:* No problem, thanks for hanging out here and asking good questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@cannyboy**:

There's a plugin called [**Search Unleashed**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-unleashed/) that gives lots of different functionality. One of my clients was using it and I was impressed with the control it gave. Not 100% sure it will give you what you need but it's worth checking out.

If your blog only has post_types of "post" and you don't use them for the rest of the site you could use *@TerryMatula*'s suggestion but with `$post_type` => `'post'` instead, i.e.:

> `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up putting this code in the text widget on my blog page (see my updated question)

Answer (score 2):

If the Blog is in its own category, you could copy the searchform.php code, and then add this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="{your category id}" />
```

of course, replacing {your category id} with the actual ID number. You could either put the entire form code into a widget, or directly into your template.